# ImportError when scheduling python code to run using crontab

Tags: python

This code runs fine from shell without errors:

```
import urllib.request
```

When I schedule for it to run using crontab, it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/pi/Documents/pyemail/ipemailer.py", line 2, in <module> 
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: sounds like you're running a python 3 shell and your system is using python 2 to execute the crontab. Can you include you entry in the crontab?

Comment: Whenever a program behaves differently when run via `cron`, it is usually due to environment differences.  In this case, check your `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` settings on the regular command line vs. in a cron environment.

Answer (score 0):

The module [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.html) was only made available starting Python3.

From the old [`urllib` docs from Python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html):

> The **urllib** module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to **urllib.request**, **urllib.parse**, and **urllib.error** error.

The `cron` utility is a system tool, which most likely also uses the system Python, which is most likely Python 2.7. You'll have to explicitly tell `cron` that you want to use Python 3 instead.

You can do this by adding a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of your Python script that specifies Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

To get the correct shebang, do:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Then in your crontab list:

```
0 5 * * 1-5 /path/to/my-python-script.py
```

Make sure to make the script executable by doing

```
$ chmod +x /path/to/my-python-script.py
$ ls -l /path/to/my-python-script.py 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.5K 10月  1 08:52 /path/to/my-python-script.py
```

---

**UPDATE**:

If you want to check which Python interpreter is being used by your script, add this at the top:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: still a no go Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2019 12:22:01 -0400
Subject: Cron <pi@raspberrypi> python /home/pi/Documents/pyemail/ipemailer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/pyemail/ipemailer.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request

Comment: i did add the correct shebang for python3 and made it excuteable as you instructed when i run it thonny it still works perfectly

Comment: @RayEttinger "_python /home/pi/Documents/pyemail/ipemailer.py_": It looks like you are calling your script with `python`, which normally points to Python2 (check with `python -V`). Even if you have the shebang for Python 3, it will be ignored if you still call the script explicitly with Python 2. Either call it with `python3` or simply use `/path/to/script.py` (as in my example) and rely on the shebang.

Comment: @RayEttinger If you want to confirm which Python interpreter is being used by your script, check my recent edit to my answer.